# Plotly px.line - do not connect data points

Tags: python, plotly

I have the below set up for a line graph (yes I know this is not yet a best practice re. data visualization...).

I don't want the line graph to connect the gaps. I tried many things yet it continues to fill the gaps.

Any thoughts on how to solve this? I'm using plotly.

[image]]

````
fig = px.line( x = x ,
              y = y,
              color = color,
              hover_name = tooltip,
              line_shape = 'spline',
              render_mode="SVG",
              #text=df2['primary_artist_name'],
              title = 'this is a graph')

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")

fig.update_traces(connectgaps=False)

fig.show()```
````

**update**

so I switched to a scatter plot and connected the dots - after sorting the dataset correctly but I still don't get a proper connection of the dots:

[image]

````
y = df['rank']

df['year'] = df['year'].apply(str)

color = df['year']

df.sort_values(by=['year', 'week', 'rank'], inplace=True)

# View the first 5 rows
print(df)

fig = px.scatter( x = x ,
              y = y,
              color = color,
              #hover_name = tooltip,
              #line_shape = 'spline',
              #trendline = 'ols',
              #trendline_scope='trace',
              render_mode="SVG",
              #text=df2['primary_artist_name'],
              title = 'Churn on Dutch Hip Hop tracks that landed an #1 position')

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")

fig.update_traces(connectgaps=True)

fig.update_traces(mode="lines+markers")

fig.show()```
````

**update**
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you need a scatter plot not a line plot.

Comment: You could add one line per color (if it is in a `pd.DataFrame`, try `.stack()` or `.pivot()`). Or add one missing value between the last value of one line and the first of the next. Also, make sure that your x values are ordered.

Comment: just updated the code and chaged it to a scatter - still unusual connection of dots. any thoughts?

Comment: Please sort your data to get more correct lines